# Why the SharePoint2013 web's author is 'i:0#.w',I never add it,Maybe the sharepoint add it automatically

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

When I use the command to get all sharepoint webs ,I found some site's Author is **'i:0#.w'**,I don't know why the sharepoint Automatically add the user.!

Here is the screen capture for the webs [image: sharepoint infromations]

Here is the MSDN article.[Plan sites and site collections in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263267(v=office.15).aspx)

```
`Get-SPWebApplication -IncludeCentralAdministration | Get-SPSite -Limit All | Get-SPWeb -Limit All | Select-Object URL, Title, Description, ParentWeb, AssociatedOwnerGroup, SiteAdministrators, WebTemplate, UIVersion, QuickLaunchEnabled, TreeViewEnabled, Language, Locale, Author, HasUniquePerm | Sort URL | export-csv <file location and name.csv>`
```

Answer (score 0):

I　find a article to describe the detail about [How-Claims-encoding-works-in-SharePoint-2010](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/How-Claims-encoding-works-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx)